# Change default fn+delete to cmd+alt+delete or cmd+delete in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way in OS X to change the default <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> to <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> or even just simply <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd>?

I use <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>[x]</kbd> for many of my shortcuts and it'd be nice to have a forward delete function the same way.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to press ⌘⌫ (read, `cmd-delete`) and get a ⌦ (`forward-delete`)? Note that the former is used in other places and using this will, for example, make it impossible to delete a file from Finder.

Comment: Ah, it sounds like I should just stick with the fn-del for now.  Thanks